# How does android handle px vs dp in the browser?

Tags: android, mobile, responsive-design, density-independent-pixel

Everything I've found so far on Android's handling of px and dp seems to be regarding native android applications.

How does Android handle websites using px in their CSS? Does it automatically convert it to the appropriate dp size?

Answer (score 1):

No AFAIK, but you can [choose different CSS stylesheets, or different rules within a stylesheet, based upon density](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#DensityCSS). This works using `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio`. Or, in JavaScript, use `window.devicePixelRatio` to determine the density.